# Where to add host name while adding pfx certificate in RestSharp using C#?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to communicate with a server where I need to pass pfx cert, host and passphrase.

To test the server, I use Postman. So I fill the certificate setting in postman, and my request works fine as shown here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7pUH.png)

I see there is a way to add pfx cert with password but how to add all 3 (**host** along with pfx cert and password)?

```
var client = new RestClient(url);
string certificatePath = @"certificates/certificate.pfx";
string pass = "password";

X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, pass);
client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { certificate };
client.Proxy = new WebProxy();

var restrequest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
restrequest.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
restrequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
restrequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(restrequest);
```

Comment: You don't have to, just use that RestClient for one domain.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. "just use that RestClient for one domain"? Do you mean passing pfx cert and passphrase is enough and we don't need to pass the hostname anywhere in restSharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PostMan, you configure the host so it doesn't use that certificate for communication with *any* host asking for a client certificate.

In your code, you can ensure that you use the RestClient that you configure with that certificate only for communication with a given host.